# Check IIS6 Meta data in windows server 2008 x64

Tags: iis, wix

when I check if IIS6 metabase has been installed , in Window server 2008 x64 enterprise Edition.
use those code :

`<Property Id="IIS_METABASE_COMPAT">
<RegistrySearch Id="CheckIISMetabase" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components" Name="ADSICompatibility" Type="raw" />
</Property>`

`<Condition Message="IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility feature must be installed">
Installed OR ((VersionNT < 600) OR IIS_METABASE_COMPAT)
</Condition>`

whether I installed the IIS6 MetaBase or not, it always say "IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility feature must be installed",I have checked ,the registKey is exist.is Wix support this Windows Version? This one already reported by some one in the bug list. please check the below url for that bug.

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3126222&group_id=105970&atid=642714

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking into the wrong place in the system registry. If your package is x86 (see [Package](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_package.htm)/@Platform attribute), and you're installing on a 64-bit (according to your question), the [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) will look 32-bit registry. See RegistrySearch/@Win64 attribute for more details.